# SQL query to report on what invoices have not been paid, ordered by invoice number

Tags: sql, oracle

new to SQL and only been doing it for a week and a half. So I apologise now for the question being simple or appearing to be stupid.

I want to present a report on invoices that have not been paid by a given date, ordered by invoice number.

This is how I have displayed, the paid invoices but without the given date.. How do I display, the invoices that have not been paid by say 31-MAR-14.

```
SELECT INVOICE.INVOICE_NUMBER, INVOICE.INVOICE_DATE, PAYMENT.PAYMENT_NO, PAYMENT.INVOICE_NUMBER
FROM INVOICE, PAYMENT
WHERE INVOICE.INVOICE_NUMBER = PAYMENT.INVOICE_NUMBER
ORDER BY INVOICE.INVOICE_NUMBER;
```

Comment: Do you have a column in PAYMENT that designates what day the the payment was made?

Comment: Yes, I have 'Payment_No' 'Payment_Method' 'Date_of_payment' and 'Invoice_number' as a foreign key. In the Payment table.

Comment: So you're looking for all invoices that have not been paid by march 31st?  Does this mean there is an entry in the PAYMENT table, where the date is > march 31st?  Or there is no entry in the payment table at all for a particular invoice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the two tables together with a `LEFT JOIN`, then look to see where the payment date is > 31-MAR-14.  Try something like this:

```
SELECT INVOICE.INVOICE_NUMBER, INVOICE.INVOICE_DATE, PAYMENT.PAYMENT_NO, PAYMENT.INVOICE_NUMBER
FROM INVOICE
LEFT JOIN PAYMENT ON INVOICE.INVOICE_NUMBER = PAYMENT.INVOICE_NUMBER
WHERE PAYMENT.Date_of_payment > '3/31/2014'
ORDER BY INVOICE.INVOICE_NUMBER;
```

This looks for all payments that were made after 3/31/2014.  You may need to add another condition, that limits what invoices you're looking for.

To check payments that have not been made, look where any field in the PAYMENT table is null.  SQL like this:

```
SELECT INVOICE.INVOICE_NUMBER, INVOICE.INVOICE_DATE, PAYMENT.PAYMENT_NO, PAYMENT.INVOICE_NUMBER
FROM INVOICE
LEFT JOIN PAYMENT ON INVOICE.INVOICE_NUMBER = PAYMENT.INVOICE_NUMBER
WHERE INVOICE.INVOICE_DATE = '3/31/2014'
AND PAYMENT.PAYMENT_NO IS NULL
ORDER BY INVOICE.INVOICE_NUMBER;
```

LEFT JOIN in this case will always return values for the INVOICE table, but may return NULL values in place of the PAYMENT if a payment has not been entered yet.  Checking `AND PAYMENT.PAYMENT_NO IS NULL` will tell you that a payment has not been made yet.

Comment: Thanks very much, But thats showing what Invoices have been paid. How would I do it if i wanted to see what invoices had not been paid?

Comment: So if a Payment has not been made yet, there should be no entry in the Payment table?  What invoice dates are you looking to filter by in this scenario?  Would an invoice date of 2/1 work, or are you only looking for invoices with a date of 3/31?

Comment: So within payment, i just have paymnet_no, payment_method, date_of_payment and Invoice_number (invoice number is foreign key from invoices). 

So in payment i have about 21 invoices that have been paid, identified by payment_no (primary key) and Invoice_number (foreign key from inovoice). What I would like to do is, is list a report on invoices that have not been paid by a given date.. then ordered by invoice number

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT PAYMENT.PAYMENT_NO
    FROM INVOICE, PAYMENT
    WHERE INVOICE.INVOICE_NUMBER = PAYMENT.INVOICE_NUMBER
    AND INVOICE.INVOICE_DATE = 'AAAAMMJJ'
    ORDER BY INVOICE.INVOICE_NUMBER;
```

Try something like this.
I have question. How do you say the invoice are not paid ?

Comment: Thanks, but thats what Im trying to work out. Im not sure how I can list all the invoices that have not been paid.